# Django: Nested variables in templates

Tags: django, django-templates

In one of my django login templates, I have a line:

`<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next|default:'{% url jobseeker_home %}' }}" />`

And when I view the source code of the HTML page generated, I get the following for the above template line:

`<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{% url jobseeker_home %}" />`

Unfortunately, the **{% url jobseeker_home %}** is not being resolved. How can I solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Variables can be declared within a Django template:

```
{% url jobseeker_home as home_url %}
<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next|default:home_url }}" />
```

Comment: awesome. I didn't know you could do that!

Comment: @Jerzyk: yes, I changed the variable name halfway through but didn't finish the job. Fixed.