# Have django pull the value of {{ variable|add:"_date" }} from context instead of just printing it

Tags: django, django-templates

I currently have a context variable called `Myvar_date`
Now in my code I am doing this

```
 {{ variable|add:"_date" }}
```

The output of above is `Myvar_date` since `variable` in above is equal to Myvar.
Now the problem that I have with above is that it is simply printing it. It is not pulling the value of that variable `Myvar_date` from the context. How do I tell django that the statement

```
{{ variable|add:"_date" }}
```

actually returns a context variable name that needs to be pulled out from the context.

Comment: Is there some reason you're trying to build variable names dynamically instead of simply typing `{{ Myvar_date }}` in your template?

Comment: You can declare the variable before its evaluation as can be seen in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5746473/django-nested-variables-in-templates) example of nested variables.